# How to convert a string to an object in C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.text.json

I want to use `System.Text.Json` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json`. But, I was unable to convert the string to an object.

Here is my request:

```json
{"Abc":'{"Property1":"abds","property2":"232"}'}
```

I've tried to parse this string by `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<A>(request)` and I'm getting an error.

How can I parse this string into an object?

Comment: What code have you written and what error do you get?

Comment: Please show us your code and what have you done. Without these details, we could not help you further and your question may risk to be closed by others.

Comment: You should explain your problem more further and with more code, that way community can give you better answer.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  The problem is that the value `'{"Property1":"abds","property2":"232"}'` of `"Abc"` is surrounded in single quotes, and single quotes are not valid string delimiters as per the [JSON Standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).  Json.NET is forgiving and parses them anyway but System.Text.Json does not.  See [System.Text.Json disallows string literals surrounded by single quotes #31608](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31608).

Answer (score 2):

First of all your json string is invalid because of single quotes, remove the single quote, create classes as follows

```
    public class Abc
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Abc Abc { get; set; }
    }
```

and then deserialize like : `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonString);`

Comment: Is the entire object invalid JSON?  Or is the entire object a normal JavaScript object which contains a single property called `Abc` whose *value* is a perfectly valid JSON string?  The question is unclear about this.

Comment: if you parse json you ll get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 7`